# How do I see why a site is "Not Secure"?

Tags: google-chrome, certificate, https, ssl-certificate

Chrome is reporting a website as "Not Secure". How can I find specific details of why it is making this assessment?

[image]
[image]

If I click the "Learn More" link, it only shows generic information on a Google.com help page.

Comment: It's your certificate to the site.  If your using a proxy that's likely the reason why

Comment: At the end of the body of the message it wil lhave a long word - like "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID".  That is the reason - you can copy and paste into Google to find out more.  Often its useful to plug the domain name into https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and it can show you if there are any issues with the "actual" certificate.  Generally the problem will be a missing root or intermediate cert.

Answer (score 0):

As seen from the image there is no certificate installed on the server or you might have installed a wrong certificate.

I feel the certificate has been installed after you have posted this query [image]